# Como alterar as cores das Notas usando javascript de acordo com o resultado

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um banco de dados onde insiro as notas dos meus alunos.
Porém gostaria que essas notas fossem mostradas no boletim virtual da seguinte forma:

Notas de 0 a 25 = Vermelho

Notas de 26 a 50 = Amarelo

Notas de 51 a 75 = Azul

Notas de 76 a 100 = Verde

Quando o aluno entrar em seu boletim virtual, terá sua notas com cores mediante ao seu desempenho.

Mas não tenho ideia de como execultar tal tarefa.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma dica de como proceder, ou mesmo onde posso aprender como fazer

Não sei se consegui me fazer entender, mas coloco-me a disposição para esclarecer quaisquer duvida.

Comment: Você vai montar uma tabela dinamicamente com o php para exibição dos dados?

Comment: Independente de PHP ou Javascript, isso com lógica resolveria, comparando o valor e, em uma lista, exibir a cor

Comment: Assim como o @WilliamAparecidoBrandino falou, a lógica é essa mesmo. Compara o valor e atribui uma classe css pra o elemento que vai englobar a nota.

Comment: Murilo, alguma das respostas resolveu o teu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As notas serão sempre números inteiros?

Se preferir usar jQuery, abaixo um exemplo simples:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>each demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="nota" id="x"><h1><b>1,3</b</h1></div><br/>
<div class="nota"><h1><b>25</b</h1></div><br/>
<div class="nota"><h1><b>2.3</b</h1></div><br/>

<div class="nota"><h1><b>26</b</h1></div><br/>
<div class="nota"><h1><b>51</b</h1></div><br/>
<div class="nota"><h1><b>100</b</h1></div><br/>

<script>

var nota;
$( "div.nota" ).each(function( index ) {
    nota = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );

    if(nota >= 0 && nota <= 25)
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    else if(nota >= 26 && nota <= 50)
        $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
    else if(nota >= 51 && nota <= 75)
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    else if(nota >= 76 && nota <= 100)
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
}
);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu @Rafael Sobreira Braga, a sua dica funcionou como uma luva.

Comment: @Murilo Cabral, fico feliz em te ajudar. Abs.

Answer (score 3):

Cria uma função que te dê essa informação e no momento de gerar passas o valor da nota e a função retorna a côr.

Algo assim:

```js
function getScoreColor(nr) {
    if (nr < 26) return 'red';
    if (nr < 51) return 'yellow';
    if (nr < 76) return 'lightblue';
    return 'green';
}


var notas = [10, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100];
var linhas = notas.forEach(function(nota){
 var p = document.createElement('p');
 p.style.backgroundColor = getScoreColor(nota);
 p.innerHTML = 'A sua nota foi ' + nota;
 document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qqmmexff/

Answer (score 0):

Após seu formulário ser carregado, no evento [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload), você pode colocar uma função que itera labels (ou inputs) e altera a cor do conteúdo de acordo com o valor. Frizando que nesse caso é a função deve ser invocada após o DOM ser completamente montado:

```js
var labels =  document.getElementById("notas").parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  
  var valor = labels[i].innerHTML;

  if (valor >= '0' && valor <= '26')
    labels[i].className = "vermelho";
  if (valor >= '26' && valor <= '50')
    labels[i].className = "amarelo";
  if (valor >= '51' && valor <= '75')
    labels[i].className = "azul";
  if (valor >= '76' && valor <= '100')
    labels[i].className = "verde";
  
};
```

```css
.vermelho {
  color: red;
}
.amarelo {
  color: yellow;
}
.azul {
  color: blue;
}
.verde {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="notas">
  <label>20</label>
  <br/>
  <label>30</label>
  <br/>
  <label>60</label>
  <br/>
  <label>80</label>
</table>
```